# Question about ε-moves at $\varepsilon NFA$

Tags: automata, finite-automata

We learning know about ε-moves at $\varepsilon NFA$ and I'm little bit confuse...

If we have, for example, this  $\varepsilon NFA$:
[image]

and we have the word "$a$" - can we end the run at $s$? Or the running will be finish at $q$?
In other words what I'm tring to ask is this:
**When we have an $\varepsilon$ - we first of all reading the letter from the input and then "jump"? or we can "jump" and then reading the input?** (or we can do both).

I look at the definition of: $\hat{\delta}(q,a)$ *(for a word)* and $\delta(q,a)$ *(for a letter)*, and I'm not sure if the answer to my question dependence at $\hat{\delta}(q,a)$ or $\delta(q,a)$, because:
$\hat{\delta}(q,a)=\{q,s\}$ and $\delta(q,a)=\{q\}$.

Thank you so much!
I hope I was clear (because I'm little bit confuse...)

Comment: You can end both in $q$ or in $s$ (and if $s$ accepting then the NFA accepts the word $a$). In other words both "computations": (1) [read a + go from state p to q] and (2) [read a + go from state p to q + go from state q to s] are valid. There is no need to do an input read to do an $\epsilon$ move.

Comment: In general, for an input letter $a$, an $\epsilon$-NFA can first take an arbitrary number of $\epsilon$-transitions, then an $a$-transition, and then another arbitrary number of $\epsilon$-transitions.

Comment: The answer is in the definition: a word is accepted if there *exists* a computation of this and that form. Unfold and you'll see that you can add $\varepsilon$-transitions wherever you want.

Comment: The confusion may be about the nondeterminism bit. In DFAs, you always have exactly one walk through the automaton for any word in $\Sigma^*$ - not so in NFAs (or $\epsilon$-NFAs): here you can have multiple walks that may or may not partially overlap, or - with $\epsilon$-transitions - you may even have separate walks where one contains the other.

Comment: @all - convert to answers?!

Answer (score 2):

In an $\varepsilon NFA$, when processing an $\varepsilon$ character, we can move on an $\varepsilon$-edge or we can stay on the state we are currently in. 
And for example since $a= \varepsilon a \varepsilon\varepsilon$, in your $NFA$ these two paths are both correct:

$$p \rightarrow^{\varepsilon} p \rightarrow^{a} q \rightarrow^{\varepsilon} s \rightarrow^{\varepsilon} s$$

and

$$p \rightarrow^{\varepsilon} p \rightarrow^{a} q \rightarrow^{\varepsilon} q \rightarrow^{\varepsilon} s$$

Therefore, with the character $a$ we have $\delta(p,a)=q$ and for the word $a$ we have $\hat{\delta}(p,a)=\{q,s\}.$

Answer (score 0):

Well we have ε-NFA to help us strengthen the theoretical world of Automata !
It's applications are not much ! we could do all these things with a NFA !

Look at the example you have given ! as you said if we have a string like : 'a'
Our state will go from 'p' to 'q' but then in 'q' we have no other character after 'a' so the state of the Automata will go from 'q' to 's' !so by other words with the string 'a' we go from 'p' to 's' ! 
so what was the point of having a middle state and then saying with empty-string it goes to the last state !?

Well look at this example : suppose Automata had a fourth state named 'g' and with the character 'b' and the state 'q' we could go to the state 'g' and the state 'g' was an accepting state ! what does that mean ? 
well it means that the string 'a' is not in the language of Automata but the string 'ab' is in the language of Automate !
Now look the string 'bba' , with the character 'b' the state will not change , but with the character 'a' we will go to the state 's' which is not an accepting state ! so the string 'bba' wont be in the language of Automata !

That means Automata will only accept the string that should start with an 'a' and should have at least one 'b'.
By other words empty-string just made our distinction between the strings that should be accepted and the strings that should not be accepted much simpler :)
I hope it helps !

Good Luck.